# added username, user unable to write to home directory

Tags: useradd

I added several users to my server using `useradd -d /home/<username> <username>` . The users are able to log in and access their directories, but get Permission denied error messages when attempting to create files or directories.

I thought that associating a home/username directory with username gives them read/write permission, and that I don't have to use chmod to give the user permissions to their own home directory. Presumably I missed a step when creating the user account, please clarify.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use option `-m` to create the home dir when doing `useradd`. `-d ...` is only to override the default name for the home dir, which is the same as the one you actually gave. You need to `chown name:name /home/name` for each name now to recover.

`-m` is useful as it also copies some standard files into the home dir.

Comment: OK, thanks. I thought that the -d argument would set permissions to the home directory. In any case, chown fixed the issue, my main concern was how to avoid having to do this in the future.